# Robolectric - how to disable a unit test?

Tags: android, junit, robolectric

I have a [robolectric unit test](http://robolectric.org/) that is work in progress. I want to disable it temporarily pending implementation, but I don't want to comment out the entire test.

How can a robolectric unit test be temporarily disabled without actually removing the test?

Comment: Nice, but question is not related to android, robolectric or gradle plugin

Comment: @EugenMartynov Technically, you are right in the sense that it's really JUnit being used/manipulated here, however using the term "Robolectric" will allow more people to find this Q/A. The Android tag is relevant in the sense that Robolectric allows Android apps to be tested on the JVM using JUnit. While Gradle is required for robolectric, you're right that it's not really related to the question, so I've removed that tag.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The JUnit [**`@Ignore`**](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Ignoring-tests) attribute can be used to temporarily disable a unit test:

```
@RunWith(MyRobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
public class TestAbc123 extends MyTestBase
{
    @Ignore   // This attribute may be removed once the test is ready
    @Test
    public void TestAbc123Scenerio1()
    {
```

Ignored tests are shown as an amber disc with horizontal bars:

[image: Ignored test output]

Answer (score 3):

To ignore a Unit test, annotate it with `@Ignore`.

You can add an optional comment to record why the test is being ignored:

```
@Ignore("Not ready yet")
@Test
public void testToIgnore()
{
    // ...
}
```